# Collate data from different Databases into same output window

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to display data in different columns in the same output window from multiple different database sources. It would be ok to output this data to a file if necessary. For example say I have the following script that I need run on databases with identical schema:

```
SELECT TOP 3 item_id, COUNT(*) as itemcount_db1 
FROM DB1.dbo.table 
GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY itemcount_db1

SELECT TOP 3 item_id, COUNT(*) as itemcount_bd2 
FROM DB2.dbo.table 
GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY itemcount_bd2
```

So that the output would not be in two sequential and separate windows (as I hundreds of DBs and want to do a single copy and paste). I'm happy to create all of the individual scripts to get the data, just need to combine them somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you can use `sp_MSforeachdb`  or a [potential better one by Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) so you don't have to copy and paste all the scripts. I'm not sure you'd want the results going horizontally here, but instead just create a column with the DB flag. Here is a way using `UNION` and a CTE (since you need the order by for `TOP`).

```
with db1 as(
    SELECT TOP 3 
        item_id, 
        COUNT(*) as itemcount
        ,'DB1'
    FROM 
        DB1.dbo.table 
    GROUP BY 
        item_id
    ORDER BY 
        itemcount_bd2)

db2 as(
    SELECT TOP 3 
        item_id, 
        COUNT(*) as itemcount
        ,'DB2'
    FROM 
        DB2.dbo.table 
    GROUP BY 
        item_id 
    ORDER BY 
        itemcount_bd2)


select * from db1
union all
select * from db2
```